# How to implement a timed trigger & execute events without scheduler in near real-time

Tags: redis, event-handling, scheduled-tasks, hazelcast, ignite

A system receives millions of events. The system is responsible to push the qualified data to the down-stream system - the qualification lies on the time it has to be triggered.

The current implementation uses scheduled jobs that periodically checks  the database for events qualified and pushes them to down-stream systems for processing.

**Problem**

- I have lots or schedulers (for different sort of works & different frequency of tasks) that keeps checking the database for tasks.
- Many times the job runs without any jobs in the database (no tasks received). The job scheduler has exponential retrieval policy to reduce the frequency it checks the database upon no data. It has its own problems like, the data stays idle without being processed until the scheduler polls it between the frequency.
- Scaling the scheduled jobs
- No real-time

**Solution Considered**

**Redis**: All events are stored in Redis with expiry set for every value the time they have to be triggered. The event listeners  listens for the key expiry-events and pushes the events to downstream systems. But the problem with this is, considering the Redis uses the pub/sub, events are lost if  subscribers do not exist at the moment of any key expiry (network, updates etc), & non persistent of this event leads to loss of events & unreliable events.

Is there any tool sets, data-structures (radix tree?) which can help to trigger timed events in near-real time?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I don't think it's a good fit for SO since there's not likely to be one definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use a combination of Change-Data-Capture and Stream Processing:

1. CDC will actively scan your table(s) for change(s)
2. It will feed the data to your data pipeline(s) for further processing

Here's the [documentation](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks#change-data-capture-cdc) for the implementation with [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) and [Hazelcast](https://jet-start.sh/docs/get-started/intro).

Comment: I am now trying this with Apache Ignite - the keys are set to expire based on different needs. Event consumers react to expiry events by broadcasting them as different types of event to which the downstream systems work.

Also I am looking into the Redis modules.